# Subset pandas data frame with multiple condition on several columns with date

Tags: python, pandas, date, dataframe

I have a data frame as follows:

```
  slot_id class        day   base_date
0        1     A     Monday  2019-01-21
1        2     B    Tuesday  2019-01-22
2        3     C  Wednesday  2019-01-23
3        4     C  Wednesday  2019-01-23
4        5     C   Thursday  2019-01-24
```

With the following info:

```
example.info()
<class 'pandas.core.frame.DataFrame'>
RangeIndex: 8 entries, 0 to 7
Data columns (total 4 columns):
slot_id      8 non-null int64
class        8 non-null object
day          8 non-null object
base_date    8 non-null object
dtypes: int64(1), object(3)
memory usage: 200.0+ bytes
```

I would like to get the row with `class == "C"` with the minimum `base_date`. I have tried many combinations of `min` without success, like this one:

```
example[(example['class']=="C") & min(example['base_date'])]
```

What's wrong with the code above? How could I get a full row meeting the condition above? 
Full `example` data frame:

```
{'slot_id': {0: 1, 1: 2, 2: 3, 3: 4, 4: 5, 5: 6, 6: 7, 7: 8}, 'class': {0: 'A', 1: 'B', 2: 'C', 3: 'C', 4: 'C', 5: 'C', 6: 'D', 7: 'E'}, 'day': {0: 'Monday', 1: 'Tuesday', 2: 'Wednesday', 3: 'Wednesday', 4: 'Thursday', 5: 'Tuesday', 6: 'Thursday', 7: 'Saturday'}, 'base_date': {0: datetime.date(2019, 1, 21), 1: datetime.date(2019, 1, 22), 2: datetime.date(2019, 1, 23), 3: datetime.date(2019, 1, 23), 4: datetime.date(2019, 1, 24), 5: datetime.date(2019, 1, 22), 6: datetime.date(2019, 1, 24), 7: datetime.date(2019, 1, 26)}}
example['base_date'] = pd.to_datetime(example['base_date'].astype(str), format='%d%m%Y')
example['base_date'] = example['base_date'].dt.date
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `idxmin`:

```
pd.to_datetime(df.loc[df['class'] == 'C', 'base_date']).idxmin()
# 2

df.iloc[pd.to_datetime(df.loc[df['class'] == 'C', 'base_date']).idxmin()]

slot_id               3
class                 C
day           Wednesday
base_date    2019-01-23
Name: 2, dtype: object
```

---

If you need to do this repeatedly, a better solution is to pre-convert "base_date" to `datetime` type:

```
df['base_date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['base_date'], errors='coerce')
df.iloc[df.loc[df['class'] == 'C', 'base_date'].idxmin()]

slot_id                        3
class                          C
day                    Wednesday
base_date    2019-01-23 00:00:00
Name: 2, dtype: object
```

Comment: This worked! :-) 
However, how would you deal with more date variables, like if you wanted the min of base_date and also subset for date_var2 to be max. Would you have to use the idxmin and idxmax separetely or can you mix them in a one-liner?

Comment: @user3507584 You want two separate rows? Or do you want a _single_ row where col1 is minimum and col2 is maximum?

Comment: I was wondering how to subset using more datetime variables. If you use the index (.idxmin) inside df.iloc, that can only refer to one variable, right? If you had a second date time variable, it looks like you would have to use df.iloc twice, once for each datetime variable you are subsetting. Am I right?

Comment: @user3507584 Hmm, I'm still having a hard time following. It would be great if you can open a follow up question with some input and expected output so I can figure out how exactly to help you. (please consider marking this accepted if it solved your problem as originally defined.)

Comment: Just posted another question with the same example https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54451643/subset-pandas-data-frame-with-datetime-columns

Comment: @user3507584 Seems like Wen-Ben as weighed in. Let me know if you still need any help on that question and I'll see what I can do.