# Subset pandas data frame with datetime columns

Tags: python, pandas, date, dataframe, subset

Following up [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54450983/subset-pandas-data-frame-with-multiple-condition-on-several-columns-with-date) where a pandas data frame is subset by one string variable and one datetime variable using `idx.min`, how could we subset by two date time variables? For the example data frame below, how would we subset rows from `class == C`, with the `minimum base_date` and the `maximum date_2` date? [answer would be row 3]:

```
print(example)
   slot_id class        day   base_date      date_2
0        1     A     Monday  2019-01-21  2019-01-24
1        2     B    Tuesday  2019-01-22  2019-01-23
2        3     C  Wednesday  2019-01-22  2019-01-24
3        4     C  Wednesday  2019-01-22  2019-01-26
4        5     C  Wednesday  2019-01-24  2019-01-25
5        6     C   Thursday  2019-01-24  2019-01-22
6        7     D    Tuesday  2019-01-23  2019-01-24
7        8     E   Thursday  2019-01-24  2019-01-30
8        9     F   Saturday  2019-01-26  2019-01-31
```

For just `class == "C"` with the `minimum base_date` we can use:

```
df.iloc[pd.to_datetime(df.loc[df['class'] == 'C', 'base_date']).idxmin()]
```

However, if we had 2 or more date variables with conditions like max/min, would the index solution still be practical? Doesn't index subsetting with 2 or more variable imply nesting `df.iloc`? Is this the only way to do the subset with 2 or more datetime variables?

Data:

```
print(example.to_dict())
{'slot_id': {0: 1, 1: 2, 2: 3, 3: 4, 4: 5, 5: 6, 6: 7, 7: 8, 8: 9}, 'class': {0: 'A', 1: 'B', 2: 'C', 3: 'C', 4: 'C', 5: 'C', 6: 'D', 7: 'E', 8: 'F'}, 'day': {0: 'Monday', 1: 'Tuesday', 2: 'Wednesday', 3: 'Wednesday', 4: 'Wednesday', 5: 'Thursday', 6: 'Tuesday', 7: 'Thursday', 8: 'Saturday'}, 'base_date': {0: datetime.date(2019, 1, 21), 1: datetime.date(2019, 1, 22), 2: datetime.date(2019, 1, 22), 3: datetime.date(2019, 1, 22), 4: datetime.date(2019, 1, 24), 5: datetime.date(2019, 1, 24), 6: datetime.date(2019, 1, 23), 7: datetime.date(2019, 1, 24), 8: datetime.date(2019, 1, 26)}, 'date_2': {0: datetime.date(2019, 1, 24), 1: datetime.date(2019, 1, 23), 2: datetime.date(2019, 1, 24), 3: datetime.date(2019, 1, 26), 4: datetime.date(2019, 1, 25), 5: datetime.date(2019, 1, 22), 6: datetime.date(2019, 1, 24), 7: datetime.date(2019, 1, 30), 8: datetime.date(2019, 1, 31)}}
```

Data pretreatment:

```
example = pd.DataFrame(example)
example['base_date'] = pd.to_datetime(example['base_date'].astype(str), format='%d%m%Y')
example['base_date'] = example['base_date'].dt.date
example['date_2'] = pd.to_datetime(example['date_2'].astype(str), format='%d%m%Y')
example['date_2'] = example['date_2'].dt.date
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can using `transform`

```
yourdf=example[example['base_date']==example.groupby('class')['base_date'].transform('min')]
```

If only for columns C

```
yourdf.loc[yourdf['class']=='C',:]
```

---

Also `idxmin` or `idxmax`  will only return the first index met the min or max condition , so when there is multiple max or min values , they are still only show one index